# What is the role of -s in this code, where s is a char pointer?

Tags: c++, c, string, character, pointer-arithmetic

In this code

```
strcpy(s, "bacalaureat");
i = strchr(s, 'a') - s; // i = 1
```

The value of `i` is 1. Why is that, and what's the role of the `-s` above?

Comment: `strchr` returns a pointer to the found position, so subtracting the pointer at the start of the string from that gives you the index of the found position. And indeed, the first `a` in `bacalaureat` is at position 1. (The `b` is at position 0).

Comment: that is basically `std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a');`

Comment: User the tag "pointer-arithmetic" on SO.

Answer (score 5):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr):

> `char *strchr( const char *str, int ch );`
>
> Finds the first occurrence of `ch` ... in the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `str`

So `strchr(s, 'a')` will return a pointer to the first occurrence of the character `a`, which is the second character in `s`.

Subtracting `s` from this result is just pointer arithmetic which gives you the index of the character `a` in `s`, which is 1.